# Jquery dialog not opening second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

Before dismissing this as a question that has already been answered, please have a look. I have implemented pretty much all the solutions provided in the other posts, with no luck. The modal opens perfectly the first time, but fails the second time.

Modal is called from here:

```
function myFx(id){
  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/mypath",
      data: { ZoneId: id },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
      }
    },
    error: function (response) {
    }
  });
 }
```

The function is inside $(document).ready(). No errors on firebug. On a button click, I call `myFx()` and pass id: `<button onclick="myFx(id)" />`.

And was initialised like this:

```
var myModal =  $('#dialog-form').dialog(
  {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 290,
    width: 475,
    buttons: {
      'Save': function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: $("#edit-book").attr('action'),
          data: $("#edit-book").serialize()+'&eZoneId=' +$('#eZoneId').val(),
          dataType: "text/plain",
          success: function (response) {
            var closeDialog = $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
            $("#grid").load('mypath/ #grid', function () {
            $('tbody > tr:first')
              .effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
        });
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
        $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
      }
    });
  },
  Cancel: function () {
    $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
  }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: Please be more specific - where is your code executed?

Comment: It's too hard to figure out what you mean by "it fails the second time." Maybe it's the POST that's failing. Make a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Omar, please, at least 2 character indentation if not 3 or 4. 1 character indents are too hard to follow for my tired eyes.

Comment: @OldPro Oh sorry! will fix it. I dont want to get your fatigued ;)

Comment: Please be sure, were your code is executed - it should be executed after document ready: use $(function(){ /* your code */ });
And second tip: if you modify the dialog (#dialog-form), you have to set the dialog-initializer again

Comment: Have edited the post.

Comment: I would not put the function into document.ready => only the dialog-initializer - you only have to open the dialog in your function

Comment: @OldPro it looks better here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sAnWb/

Comment: Okay. Did that. No luck. My thing is, I have to call an ajax function which will populate the form on the dialog,..then on clicking save, another ajax ajax call is made to save the data and the modal is then closed. It works fine the first time though. That is what I am not getting. Some post I read suggested that the dialog should initialised into a variable.. tried that, but still failing..

Comment: try that: http://jsfiddle.net/Uqafd/

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the below line before ajax call.

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
```