# JQuery dialog not opening second time on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, webforms

this is my code to open a jquery dialog. it works first time (gets opened) but not second time (not opening). a similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039654/jquery-dialog-not-opening-second-time) but that is not working for me

```js
function LoadGridView(id, row) {
  var dlg = jQuery('#Edit').load('Edit.aspx');

  dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'slide',
    close: 'slide',
    width: 400,
    height: 160,
    buttons: {
      "cancel": function() {
        dlg.dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  

  dlg.dialog("open");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **dlg** scope does not exist when you try to open second time, you need to store it globally

```js
// global var to hold dlg
var dlg;

$(document).ready(function() {

 // get element and store it in dlg global var so that its scope may retain
  dlg = $("[id$='Edit']");


  dlg.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'slide',
    close: 'slide',
    width: 400,
    height: 160,
    buttons: {
      "cancel": function() {
        dlg.dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: oh my bad, i was messing up with scope :( this perfectly solved my problem. thanks